# The color picker in macOS Ventura screen shot tool does not open. Any ideas how to fix that?

Tags: screen-capture, bug, ventura

When I take a screenshot with SHIFT + CMD + 5 and try to open the color picker via *Show colors...* to choose a custom border color, nothing happens.

[image: Show colors]

If I do the same thing in Preview, the color picker opens as expected.

[image]

How can I fix the color picker in the screenshot tool? This is happening on a brand new MacBook Pro running macOS Ventura 13.2.1.

Comment: This isn't something I really use, but a quick test showed the colour picker opened *behind* the image I was editing [& stayed behind it even whilst interacting with it]. I only saw it because the image was quite small.

Comment: @Tetsujin I just created a tiny screenshot to test your suggestion, but the problem persists. There is no color picker seen anywhere. I minimized all other apps and double-checked this.

Comment: Ah, OK. I can't repro, sorry. Wish you luck.